# Connecting to MongoDB from Node.js causes Node to hang

Tags: node.js

Below is my code in app.js file. When I execute this code it gets
connected to MongoDB and displays 'Connected to DB' message.

But once the message gets displayed I was expecting the program to end; 
instead the program continues to run.

Why does the program continues to run and not end after printing the text?

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const co = require('co');

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test9";

co(function *() {
    db = yield MongoClient.connect(url);
    console.log('Connected to DB');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not closing the connection, Node has no idea that you're done with it and it will remain running.

When you close it, the process will exit properly:

```
co(function *() {
  let db = yield MongoClient.connect(url);
  console.log('Connected to DB');
  yield db.close();
});
```

Comment: Have one more question , If I add yield app.listen(3009 , function() {
    console.log('Connected to Server.');
  });   after "'Connected to DB', why does it not print 'Connected to Server.' , is it the correct approach. Thanks

Comment: `yield` only works with [_"yieldables"_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co#yieldables), and I'm pretty sure that `app.listen()` doesn't return one.

Comment: I am sorry for prolonging  ,  my intention is to "listen" only after I get connected to MongoDB, for that what needs to be modified ?

Comment: In that case, you should be able to just call `app.listen()` and not prefix it with `yield`.